# UIElement's member not found when called using object

Tags: uwp

Here is my function to find ActualWidth of an UIElement, it may be any UIElement including Textbox, TextBlock, Grid etc. When I send my targetElement to a function and find the ActualWidth using dot operator, it does not recognize the member of Textbox, here in my case, the 'ActualWidth' member. why this happens? How to solve this?

```
private void FindActualWidth(UIElement targetElement)
{
    double myActualWidth = targetElement.ActualWidth;
    //Error: UIElement does not contain definition for 'ActualWidth'
}

//Usage
FindActualWidth(TextBox1);
FindActualWidth(Grid1);
```

If I use it like, double myActualWidth = ((TextBox)targetElement).ActualWidth; it works without issue, but the targetElement may not be TextBox always! So it will be better, if I could use the class name, but no guess how to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct: UIElement doesn't have an ActualWidth property.

You are correct that you need to cast down from UIElement to a class that defines ActualWidth. It doesn't need to be the most derived class (e.g. TextBox). It can be any class that the object inherits from. You don't need to guess this class: you can find the class which defines ActualWidth in the documentation.

Search the docs for ActualWidth we find it defined by UIElement's child, [FrameworkElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualwidth). Since you know that TextBox works you can also look it up there: the [TextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox).ActualWidth docs it says it's inherited from FrameworkElement

You can change your code to cast to the FrameworkElement to get the ActualWidth property, and that will work for everything that has an ActualWidth:

```
private void FindActualWidth(UIElement targetElement)
{
   double myActualWidth = (targetElement as FrameworkElement)?.ActualWidth;
    //No error: FrameworkElement defines 'ActualWidth'
}
```